# Hierarchy of controllers ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, cocoapods, viewcontroller

How to get all controllers(ViewControllers/NavigationController/TabbarController) hierarchy from top to root controller?

For example I want to get all tree of controllers and after check/update some of them.

```
    ROOT
     |
VC1------VC2
          |
         NVC2
          |
        VC2.1---VC2.2-NVC3-VC3.1 etc.
```

Does exist some open solution?

Comment: There is no out of the box control on xcode to do that, However you can trace this while you are moving from one vc to another.

Comment: @BashirSidani thanks for comment, I will write some vc processing by myself.

Comment: you are most welcomed! If you feel my answer is correct please tell me to put it as answer instead of comment and accept it :)